# UIButton label doesn't appear on UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton, interface-builder

I user Interface Builder to position a UIButton and a UIImageView superimposed.
In the code, I change button label if image exists

In Example.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *takePicture;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
```

In Example.m

```
[self.image setImage:aPhoto];
(...)
NSString    *pictureButtonTitle     = myCondition@"Changer la photo":@"Ajouter une photo";
(...)
[self.takePicture   setTitle:pictureButtonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I use this code for a view, and I see "Change picture" correctly on my picture when myCondition is true.
But in another view, nothing appears !! WHY ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either do it in the interface builder - as you did, or do it in your viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.button];
}
```

Arranging the outlets in the IB as you did mean that the lower object will be on top of the others... The button will be "front"/on top when it is placed below all other objects as you shown in the screenshot.

If you wish to arrange the outlets differently, you could use these methods as well:

```
[self.view insertSubview:self.button aboveSubview:self.imageView];
```

Or:

```
[self.view insertSubview:self.imageView belowSubview:self.button];
```

Comment: Thank you, I prefer your way !

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found out : in Interface Builder, it seems that the order you place your objects matters

If you place an UIImageView before UIButton, it works well.

[image]

I see the label

[image]

But if you do the reverse : button is under the image.

[image]

And the label is not displayed

[image]

I still don't know if it's the only way to rearrange these items ?